# Run a Python file on a CSV file as soon as it is created in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, automation

I have a Python script that parses information in CSV format that's output by another software program.  I want to be able to have this process be automatic, e.g. as soon as I save the exported CSV, it is automatically parsed by the Python script.  I did a bit of research and I think I'd like to use something like inotify for Linux that is mentioned in another question here, but for Windows.  Could anyone give me any pointers? Much appreciated, thanks.